# spark-solr CDH job fails with java.lang.VerifyError at solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil

Tags: apache-spark, solr, sbt, solrj, cloudera-cdh

I'm running CDH 5.7.1 and submitting a Spark job that uses [spark-solr](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr/) 2.0.1 in yarn-cluster mode and the job is failing with the error below that arises from a (possibly) binary compatibility issue in org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil. The job runs fine in local mode allowing me to index a Spark dataframe to Solr 6.1.0.

I'm building the fat jar that is deployed to the cluster with the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin, see below for my build.sbt configuration.

I've tried various things to fix this such as specifying the --jars argument with spark-submit to provide the appropriate solr-solrj and httpclient jars with no luck, as well as numerous build.sbt changes to specify versions of solrj and httpclient explicitly, again with no luck.

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Spark job history error from yarn-cluster mode:

```
16/07/21 02:10:07 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpClientUtil.createClient(Lorg/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams;Lorg/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient; @58: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @58
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams', 'org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager', 'org/apache/solr/common/params/ModifiableSolrParams', 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: bb00 0359 2ab7 0004 4db2 0005 b900 0601
    0x0000010: 0099 001e b200 05bb 0007 59b7 0008 1209
    0x0000020: b600 0a2c b600 0bb6 000c b900 0d02 002b
    0x0000030: b800 104e 2d2c b800 0f2d b0            
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@47,Object[#143])
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2232)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3969)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4829)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$.getCachedCloudClient(SolrSupport.scala:93)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrSupport$.getSolrBaseUrl(SolrSupport.scala:97)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.util.SolrQuerySupport$.getUniqueKey(SolrQuerySupport.scala:82)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.rdd.SolrRDD.<init>(SolrRDD.scala:32)
    at com.lucidworks.spark.SolrRelation.<init>(SolrRelation.scala:63)
    at solr.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:26)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
    at com.tempurer.intelligence.searchindexer.SolrIndexer3$.runJob(SolrIndexer3.scala:127)
    at com.tempurer.intelligence.searchindexer.SolrIndexer3$.main(SolrIndexer3.scala:80)
    at com.tempurer.intelligence.searchindexer.SolrIndexer3.main(SolrIndexer3.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:542)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
```

I'm building the Spark app as a fat jar with the sbt-assembly plugin and here is my build.sbt file:

```
name := "search-indexer"
version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Cloudera CDH 5.0"        at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop"           % "hadoop-common"           % "2.6.0-cdh5.7.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.hadoop"           % "hadoop-hdfs"             % "2.6.0-cdh5.7.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.hive"             % "hive-exec"               % "1.1.0-cdh5.7.0",
  "org.apache.spark"            % "spark-core_2.10"         % "1.6.0-cdh5.7.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark"            % "spark-sql_2.10"          % "1.6.0-cdh5.7.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark"            % "spark-catalyst_2.10"     % "1.6.0-cdh5.7.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark"            % "spark-mllib_2.10"        % "1.6.0-cdh5.7.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark"            % "spark-graphx_2.10"       % "1.6.0-cdh5.7.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark"            % "spark-streaming_2.10"    % "1.6.0-cdh5.7.0" % "provided",
  "com.databricks"              % "spark-avro_2.10"         % "2.0.1",
  "com.databricks"              % "spark-csv_2.10"          % "1.4.0",
    "com.lucidworks.spark"        % "spark-solr"              % "2.0.1",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"  % "jackson-core"            % "2.8.0",  // Solves runtime error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
  "org.scalatest"               % "scalatest_2.10"          % "2.2.4"          % "test"
)

// See: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
   {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
   }
}
```

More info, including the logged YARN context can be found in this github project ticket I opened: https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr/issues/75

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue. Have you been able to resolve this question?